# Get results from relationships properties without square brackets?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, non-relational-database

In Cypher Neo4j Graph Database, I want to get the results of query in strings without square brackets.
Every time I retrieve information from nodes properties, I get the results in strings as expected but when I retrieve information from relationships, It displayed inside square brackets.

```
MATCH (m:Movie {title:"The Matrix"})<-[r:ACTED_IN]-() return r.roles;
```

Results:

```
[Agent Smith]
[Morpheus]
[Trinity]
[Neo]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get the square brackets is that the `roles` property of the `ACTED_IN` relationships is a [list](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/introduction/#graphdb-neo4j-properties).

You can use [`UNWIND`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-unwind) to expand a list (including lists of one-element) to rows:

```
MATCH (m:Movie {title:"The Matrix"})<-[r:ACTED_IN]-()
UNWIND r.roles AS roles
RETURN roles
```

If I run it on the Matrix dataset provided in this [tutorial](https://neo4j.com/developer/example-project/#_data_setup), I get:

```
╒═══════════╕
│roles      │
╞═══════════╡
│Agent Smith│
├───────────┤
│Emil       │
├───────────┤
│Trinity    │
├───────────┤
│Morpheus   │
├───────────┤
│Neo        │
└───────────┘
```